# Cisco Router not displaying DHCP client hostnames

Tags: cisco, router, dhcp-server

I've got a branch office configured to issue IP address from a Cisco Router (IOS 15.0).  The router is successfully issuing DHCP addresses just fine.  My questions is that when I issue the command "sh ip dhcp binding" it doesn't show the hostnames of the DHCP clients. It does show the IP address and MAC address.

Is there a command I'm missing that would provide this information?  I can upgrade the OS on the router if needed to gain this information.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: `I've got a branch office configured to issue IP address from a Cisco Router (IOS 15.0).` - It's a good thing Cisco only makes 1 router so that we don't have to guess which one you have.

Comment: It's a Cisco 2911 ISRG2 router

Answer (score 1):

I am 95% sure the DHCP server in Cisco IOS doesn't record this information at all. You'll need to run your DHCP server somewhere else, or collect the hostnames through some other mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Phil for the response.  I was hoping I missed this feature.  Kinda funny that my little old linksys WRT54G maintains the hostnames in it's DHCP table :)